# On hover, change another element CSS

Tags: jquery, css, hover

Have a fairly simple question for a jQuery developer out there.  I'm attempting to change a CSS attribute for an element when I hover over a different element in the page.

I've put together a fiddle for review, I'm just wondering which part I screwed up.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jodriscoll/cTeV5/)

```
$('a[href*='our_work']').hover(function(){
    $('div[id*="HM_Menu562"]').css({ top: '50' });
}, function(){
    $('div[id*="HM_Menu562"]').css({ top: '105' });
});
```

Please be aware, I'm working with my clients code and I'm very limited to modifying what currently exists.

Comment: what do you want to achieve?... use `#id` selectors for ids please http://jsfiddle.net/cTeV5/18/

Comment: What is the star for?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Be more specific please

Comment: @bbuecherl - That is for personal preference and shouldn't effect the jQuery.  Let's focus on the issue here.

Comment: @user689 - I'm not sure what you're referring to, but if it's "href*", I'm targeting any anchor tag that contains the href string "our_work".

Comment: its not about personal preference, its about performance.

Comment: @FreshPro - I explain what I'm doing in the JavaScript window of the jsFiddle (which you have to view to troubleshoot).  But, I'll post it here as well:
// The point is that when a user hovers over the "OUR WORK" button,
// A CSS style value will be changed and then reverted on mouseOut.

Comment: @bbuecherl - I didn't think my ticket had to do with performance.  Let's stick to the issue, I have to work within the standards of my client.  Thanks.

Comment: maybe b/c you don't specify unit in your css? `.css({ top: '105' });` try `'105px'`

Comment: @ZachL - The issue has already been resolved by nnnnnn.  Also you don't specific px units with .css() in jQuery.

Comment: @JoeyO'Driscoll wonderful! glad you got that sorted out. (bet there was some indication (syntax error) in the JS console about that). And *you* might not specify px units with `.css()`, but I do ;-)

Comment: Note that you may want to specify a unit _other_ than `px`, e.g., `.css({top : '105pt'});`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error in that you didn't properly nest or escape your quotes:

```
$('a[href*='our_work']').hover(function(){
```

Should be:

```
$('a[href*="our_work"]').hover(function(){
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cTeV5/19/

Comment: Perfect, I knew I missed something small but important.  Thanks!

Comment: Would you happen to have any recommendations on consolidating my jQuery on the current fiddle? (http://jsfiddle.net/jodriscoll/cTeV5/)

Comment: I would definitely extract `$('#HM_Menu571')` into a variable so you're not looking it up over and over, or even the mouseover/mouseout functions themselves. Maybe something like this?: http://jsfiddle.net/cTeV5/45/

Comment: @ZachL - Thanks for the start!  However, the menu suffix (numbers) changes for each link group.  Meaning A is associated with Menu1, B is associated with Menu2, C is associated with Menu3, etc.

Comment: Oh yes. Duh!. Somehow missed that.